# proof about the norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n×m$ matrix and $T : \mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be the linear transformation $T: x\to Ax$. Let $N$ (resp. $M$) be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (resp. $\mathbb{R}^m$) equivalent to the $\infty$-norm. Define $\|A\|$ to be 
$$
\|A\|= \sup\limits_{x\neq 0}\left\{\frac{N(Ax)}{M(x)}\right\}.
$$

Prove that $||A||=\underset{M(x)=1}{\sup}${$N(A(x)$}.

(How to prove this? does it mean $M(x)≥1$?)

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: Ian, you've asked close to 40 questions, but accepted only a small handful. It discourages users from trying to help because it may seem as though you don't find answers helpful.

Comment: @amWhy: as did this comment...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $y=\frac{x}{M(x)}$. Then $\frac{N(Ax)}{M(x)}=N(Ay)$ (really? why?). What can you say about $M(y)$?

Comment: I don't really understand, how can you connect M(x/M(x)) with N(Ax)/M(x)? Can you give a complete proof? Thanks.

Comment: Did you see my comment? Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: @i_a_n, patience, patience. Just because someone takes over $12$ minutes (!) to reply to you....

Comment: Gerry Myerson: Can you help me with this question?

Comment: @i_a_n Well, at least you should answer this question first: what is $M(x/M(x))$?

Comment: @uswe1551 I think it's just M(x)/M(x). I got it. Thanks.